# Disable submit if the username is not available php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to develop a form to create a category.

I have written a code to check the availability of the Category Name while user is typing the category name.

This is the html code I have used in the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Category Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
 <input type="text" name="category_name" class="form-control" id="category_name">
 <div id="cat_name_status" class="mt-1"></div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" name="create" id="create" type="submit">Create</button>
```

What i need is, if the Category name is not available (already taken) the submit button should be disable.

This is the jquery script I am using.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
       $("#category_name").keyup(function(){
    
          var cat_name = $(this).val();
          var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    
          if(cat_name != ''){
    
             $.ajax({
                url: 'cat_name_status.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {cat_name: cat_name},
                success: function(response){               
                    $('#cat_name_status').html(response);                    
                 }
             });
          }else{
             $("#cat_name_status").html("<span style='color: red;'> <i class='fas fa-times-circle'></i> Enter a valid category name</span>");
             $("#create").attr("disabled", true);
          }
    
        });
    
     });
    </script>
```

and this is the php code in **cat_name_status.php**

```
<?php
     require('../../dbc/dbconn.php');
     include('../../includes/scripts.php');
     include('../../includes/functions.php');
     if(isset($_POST['cat_name'])){
        $cat_name = clearInput($condb, $_POST['cat_name']);
        $check = mysqli_query($condb, "
          select cat_name 
          from pos_categories 
          where cat_name = '$cat_name'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($check)>0){
            echo '<p class="text-danger"><strong><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Category Name already exists</strong></p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

At this moment, this code successfully prints the availability of the category name in **cat_name_status** div but need your support to modify it to disable the submit button if the category name is not available.

At this moment, this code successfully prints the availability of the category name in **cat_name_status** div but need your support to modify it to disable the submit button if the category name is not available.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a PHP problem, a jQuery problem, or an AJAX problem?

Comment: Also, be warned that your `SELECT`  query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: Your code might not work properly on a laggy connection. Typing could overtake the ability of the server to respond, and responses might be received out of order.

Comment: In case you don't care about any of this, and just wait until someone answers: You can disable the submit button with: `$('#create"]').prop('disabled', true);` and use `false` to enable it again.

Comment: As kiko said, it will work with `.prop(` additionaly i recommend you to "rate-limit/throttle" the ajax calls so that you do not make 20 calls when typing 20 characters

Answer (score 1):

rather than printing the error message as a string, you could use an object and encode it to JSON format to better communicate with client:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0) {
        $response = (object)[
            'code' => 1,
            'message' => '<p class="text-danger"><strong><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Category Name already exists</strong></p>'
        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

then you can parse the JSON and take action based on the "code" property of the returned object:

```
success: function(response){             
            var result = $.parseJSON(response);
            if(result.code == "1"){
                $('#cat_name_status').html(result.message);      
                $("#create").prop("disabled", true);              
            }
}
```

Why printing an object in JSON format makes the client-server communication better: because it provides a clean and flexible way to receive multiple data type structures in an AJAX call. In your specific case, you required two pieces of information from the server: an integer code indicating the scenario that occurred, and a string message containing the corresponding error message to be displayed to the user. By using JSON, you can easily receive both pieces of data in a clear and organized format that can be efficiently processed by the client-side code.

Comment: You don't mention why JSON will make the server communicate better with the client.

Comment: It is the use of an object that makes the communication better and not the JSON itself,
Printing a JSON string in response to an AJAX call is just a good approach because it allows the server to send data in a format that can be easily consumed by the client-side JavaScript code.

Comment: I agree: You can send **structured data** with JSON. It is sometimes difficult to express why a certain approach is better. I think that using JSON is indeed **more flexible**. It allows you to easily expand code in the future, or add debug information. JSON also correctly displays in the browser's developer tools. JQuery even has a [shorthand AJAX call](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for it.

Comment: @mondersky
I have modified the code it shows the following. `{"code":1,"message":"

<\/i> Category Name already exists<\/strong><\/p>"}`

Comment: can you elaborate ? because that's precisely what it is supposed to show

Comment: @mondersky - It prints the exactly same text I have written in my previous comment and it does not disable to submit too.
I have used the code mentioned by you

Comment: does it display the message "Category Name already exists" in html ? is there any error message in the console ?